# Enable Partner User Not available on Contacts

Tags: apex, contact, salesforce-classic

I cannot see Enable Partner User option on Contact detail page under Manager External User Button.
There are Partner Community Licenses available but still I cannot see enable partner user option under contact. Can anyone help me with this requirement.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account itself must first be enabled as a partner account. If I recall correctly, You cannot enable a single account for both, so you'd need to create a new account.

Answer (score 0):

My account was "Partner Account" and I have both Partner Community and Partner Community Login user licenses. But I still did not see "Enable Partner User" option for contact. The same behavior was in classic and lightning.

But the answer was simple. You need add to add needed button to the page layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not just the page layout, also the flexipage for the Highlights Panel standard component ‍♂️
If it's not there, Add Action
[image]